# How to apply specific number of users for specific time by generating the x no of requests for a set of HTTP requests

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have a scenario where i have to configure the performance testing plan for below cases. I am not sure if configurations are correct and these ultimate thread group and throughout shaping timer will be applied on multiple https requests under ultimate thread group.

## Details:-
Step 1

No of Users to load and apply load for 1st Hour = 50
Total number of request that needs to be generated = 5500/3600 = 1.527777777777778 per second

## Step 2

No of Users to load and apply load for 2nd Hour = 65
Total number of request that needs to be generated = 9100/3600 = 2.527777777777778 per second

## Step 3

No of Users to load and apply load for 3rd Hour = 80
Total number of request that needs to be generated = 12700/3600 = 3.527777777777778 per second

## Step 4

No of Users to load and apply load for 4th Hour = 95
Total number of request that needs to be generated = 16300/3600 = 4.527777777777778 per second

and so on to 8th hour by adding 15 users in each hour into previous users and 3600 more requests in previous no of requests.

I have configured the ultimate thread group and Throughput Shaping Timer as shown below.

[Ultimate Thread Group Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awGet.png)

[throughput shaping timer configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPaHP.png)

[multiple http requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgVEs.png)

Configurations can be seen here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1OqTwvl7gA

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure that your "configurations" are correct you can check the number of users and the number of requests per second using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) charts (can be installed as a part of **3 Basic Graphs** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

If you want to do a dry-run before putting the actual "load" you can use i.e. [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/), it doesn't generate any requests but you can test your ramp-up period, Timers, Post-Processors, etc.

Comment: i need your expert opinion basically. I will dry run them but if possible please have a look. Thanks

Comment: If you need my opinion: I wouldn't call the "load" of less than 2 requests per second a "performance test", moreover there is no such a thing as a "performance test", it's an umbrella term for activities related with assessing system performance like [load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing), [stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing), etc. See [What Is Performance Testing vs. Load Testing vs. Stress Testing?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing)

Comment: thanks for correcting me regarding definitions. You are right about no of requests. These are less no of request per seconds but my concern is regarding the configurations, are those configurations are correct? No of requests can be increase.